# How do I programmatically prevent users from uploading the same app to one store?

Tags: android, certificate

Let's say I have a private app store like Google Play Store for Android.

I want to prevent users (developers) to clone apps of other developers to our store. Because some are just too lazy to develop one for themselves.

**For example:**

I have Candy Crush Saga on our store which is #1 on everything. The game is so good others just want to clone the game and change its packageName, name, icons then upload it to our store (a web/windows application) just to get free users.

How do I prevent that programmatically?

We sure have people to do that kind of job but if we want to prevent that from the ground up.

Comment: Why to share the source code?

Comment: You can't restrict others from uploading the same app. It is not about who does the app first. It is about making the best and you did. The count shows it all. Competition must be there, then only great products come.

Comment: clone? how could they clone?, if code you share, why share? if not, how they make? ... disassemble APK, get source, change packagename, app name and icon? I'm hearing something similar with AdRocket ...

Comment: @user1728071: I'm talking literally about programming. I agree with what you said but by restricting users from cloning apps we would help building a healthy competition.